# Problem with endfloat in combination with sidewaystables

Tags: longtable, rotating, endfloat, sidewaystable

I am using `endfloat` and `pdflscape` to create sidewaystables at the end of my document. The problem is I want to generate a long sidewaystable, i.e. over 2 pages. However, the second part of the table (on the second page) is much different from the first, i.e. in the amount of columns etc. So I made a new sidewaystable. This looks perfectly fine in the normal document (looks as one full table over 2 pages), but with endfloat, 2 links will be generated, as one would expect, instead of only one for the first table.

Is there any way to fix this? I.e. within the table there should be only one link:
[Table 1 about here...],

instead of two links. So the link [Table 2 about here...] should be removed.

Example to show the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{endfloat}

\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\noindent
\captionbox{This is the first table.\label{tab:one}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
  \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} \\ \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\noindent
\captionbox{This is the second table.\label{tab:two}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
  \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} \\ \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}

\section{End}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: BTW, you can use longtable in landscape mode.  See page 9 of the endfloat manual wrt longtable.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks yeah I realized. Unfortunately now I have already used `sidewaystable` for my analysis because I didn't have tables which were longer than 2 pages in general. I thought maybe there is a solution for this as well; if not, I will have to change all the code I guess

Comment: What you have are two tables, with two captions and two table numbers.  Even the list of tables is confused.

Comment: @JohnKormylo sorry, indeed. I changed the captions/labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way endfloat works is that is detects the start of certain environments and clips the code from there to the end of the environment out of the document and into another file.  You can put pretty much anything inside the environment, including several pages worth of floats or non-floats.

This solution uses a wrapper environment to do precisely that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{endfloat}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{}{}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{wrapper}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}% to check for conflicts

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\begin{wrapper}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\noindent
\captionbox{This is the first table.\label{tab:one}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
  \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} \\ \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\noindent
\captionbox{This is the second table.\label{tab:two}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
  \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} \\ \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{wrapper}

\section{End}
\end{document}
```